# Can I use fragment.getContext at lower than API 23?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm making now googleMap Fragment.

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());

        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        googleMap.addMarker();

        ...
    }
```

But in this code, getContext is available for API 23 or more.
Is there a method instead getContext??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**`public static synchronized int initialize (Context context)`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapsInitializer)
>
> Initializes the Google Maps Android API so that its classes are ready
>   for use. If you are using MapFragment or MapView and have already
>   obtained a (non-null) GoogleMap by calling getMapAsync() on either of
>   these classes, then it is not necessary to call this.

**`if(FRAGMENT)`** Then

You should use [**`getActivity()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity())

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getActivity()` instead of `getContext()`;

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Application instance's `getApplicationContext()` method

Comment: Are you sure ??

Comment: I do not have tested,but i think it will be useful